# msclr\marshal_cppstd.h error when open on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, command-line-interface

i develop some function using visual studio 2015 that include

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>;
```

when i try to open on visual studio 2013,

```
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hDesktop'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hDesktop'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hDesktop'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'hDesktop'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hdesk'
error C2377: 'HDESK' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HDESK' to 'BOOL'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HDESK' to 'BOOL'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HDESK' to 'BOOL'
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HDESK' to 'BOOL'
```

what it can happen?
can some one tell me why?

this the code

```
    #include "Stdafx.h"
#include "Image.h"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
    Image::Image(System::String^ path)
    {
        std::string str = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(path);
        _mat = new cv::Mat();
        (*_mat) = cv::imread(str);
    }
```

the code running well in visual studio 2015, but in vs2013. it's not working

Comment: You need to share more info, ideally check the source code of that linked file, as it seems that the file is where the error is.

Comment: @DanielBrose this sampe code daniel. please tell me what happen

Comment: I cant say at a glance, but pls edit your question to remove first line in error code block unless it actually printing that first line too. The first error looks to be syntax, i cant see a missing close there, but worth checking elsewhere for it and if possible removing code sections till you find point when issue disapears, to be certain its actually those lines you shared at fault. There should also be a stacktrace, you can see when the first error occured and jump to that position - its a matter then of chasing all code before then (including in calling functions) to see if issue is there

Comment: i dont know, why every i added <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>, my project always error. and the error is always about winuser.h

Comment: You are battling a macro.  Omitting the line numbers from the error messages doesn't help us help you.  Swap the two #includes and you'll know more.

Comment: that is c++ code, so please remove the 'c' tag